# How to add aar in Titanium Module

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

.aar files are becoming more and more common in different 3rd part Android SDK. And Appcelerator Titanium Doesn't support them.

So one of the main Titanium advantage ( to create native modules ) is useless.

So, anyone knows how to use the "res" from the .aar file in the module. They have to be accessible as resources from the native sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hyperloop to put `aar` and `.jar` files into your `app/platform/android` directory and require them afterwards. Note that Hyperloop requires a Pro license to work with your plan.

Some references:

- [Hyperloop Android Programming Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide)
- [Hyperloop Examples (using .aar files)](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples)

And for your `res` question: For the [Ti.Facebook](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook) module, the Facebook Android SDK (.aar) is extracted and the `res` directory as well as the resulting `.jar` file are integrated [in the filesystem](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/tree/master/android).